# If/Elif not working as expected. Beginner level

Tags: python, if-statement

```
temperature = 31
if temperature >= 15:
    print("It's ok")
elif temperature >= 30:
    print("It's nice")
print ("done")
```

Comment: What is the question? Please describe what is the expected behavior and show the actual result

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell this is the code you have:

```
temperature = 31
if temperature >= 15:
    print("It's ok")
elif temperature >= 30:
    print("It's nice")
print("done")
```

Running this code will give you an output of "It's ok" followed by "done". It will not output "It's nice" because although 31 is greater than 30, it is also greater than 15 which is evaluated first. If the desired output is "It's nice", change the code to the following:

```
temperature = 31
if temperature >= 15 and temperature < 30:
    print("It's ok")
elif temperature >= 30:
    print("It's nice")
print("done")
```

then an output greater than 15 but greater than 30 will skip the first branch and evaluate at the second. Let me know if you need more clarification!

Answer (score 0):

The way you always have to imagine `if-else` in any programming language is `if something is true then do THIS, otherwise do THAT`. The `elif` is only a shortcut for another if statement INSIDE the else-branch of the former one.

This explains why you do think your example does not work is that `temperature>=30` is impossible in the `else` branch of `temperature>=15`.

This is just logic you have to get used to.